# How to fetch Domain names using twitter4j?

Tags: java, python, twitter, tweepy, twitter4j

I am a java developer and new to twitter4j API.For a part of  my application I have a necessity to fetch domain names which ends with **.com.au** and **.co.nz** from twitter users profile.I  researched a lot but unable to find any solution.Even if the solution was in Python or Scala I can manage to integrate that part with my application.

Is there any way to achieve this using twitter4j or any other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Pattern` and `Matcher` for this, try

```
ArrayList<String> domains = new ArrayList<>();

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z0-9\\-.]+)\\.co(\\.nz|m\\.au)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

while (m.find()) {
    String match = m.group();
    domains.add(match);
}
```

where `str` is the source string you want - a tweet, someone's bio, or anything. `match` will hold the necessary domain names.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. May you please confirm that is it possible to search old data in twitter using twitter4j and is there any limit when ingesting data using twitter4j.

Comment: @Arun Search results are limited to recent 7 days for Standard Search API, and not limited for Premium API. See https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets.html.